# Fuseki GeoSparql Doesnot display wktLiterals

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki, rdflib

Jena Fuseki shows successful storage of values with datatype GEO["wktLiteral"] in screenshot1 , But when using it in sparql endpoint shows different format. Please suggest me regarding this.

```
Stores in right format : <x:>    <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT>
                "POLYGON(())"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral> .
```

When I execute query :

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
FROM <http://project/base/default1>
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

It produces results as shown below.

```
s                          p                                o
1   
<x:>                    geo:asWKT                     "POLYGON(())"^^
```

Thanks,
Manoj

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the "raw response" you will see that the literal is returned with the correct datatype. It is the display (a 3rd party component) that chooses to display the data with the full URI of the datatype, presumable for presentation reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am happy that literals are getting stored with datatype. Now I am trying to check the spatial relations and I get empty results for "geo:sfEquals" filter function for two simple literals. ["LINESTRING (0 0, 0 10)" and "LINESTRING (0 0, 0 5, 0 10)" which are spatially equal ] . Attached are the screenshots for the same issue. Please suggest me regarding this. Any comments regarding the same

Comment: Can you post a separate question for this? It’s very different to your first question in this post which @AndyS has answered, so you should mark his answer accepted.